# autoscaling is not working in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The autoscale property is not working properly. WinForm was developed in high resolution. But when we deployed in a lower version of windows XP, some of the buttons are not being displayed.

I have tried several modification suggested in google but nothing seems to be working. 
here is my winform configuration.

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(grap.DpiX, grap.DpiY);
           // this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1366, 50);
            this.DockTop = true;
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Advise on how to go abt this issue might be helpful.

Comment: you need to resize the form's controls while form size increases/decreases?

Comment: @PraveenVR I need the form to re-size when the resolution changes. Right now the client is using lower resolution 1024X758. where as my application is designed for higher resolution. In my laptop I able to see all controls in my form, but in client only 3/4th is being displayed.

Comment: You've been editing the InitializeComponent() method into undiagnosable oblivion.  (96F, 96F) are never correct values.  Editing like this just digs you a deeper hole that also prevents you from getting help.  Restore from source control and shows what it *really* looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem due to the fluidity of controls.

To solve this issue, you need to design your form in low resolution(means while doing form design you have to keep its width and height below 1024*768). Then  you have to set the **Anchor** property of each controls in your form to position its correct location.

For ex: Suppose you have a Datagridview in your form, then you have to set its Anchor property as  **Top, Bottom, Left, Right**.

appropriate setting of Anchor property for each control will make the controls in a form will be stretched while the form resizes.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I dont want to hardcode the width and height. I want my forms to auto adjust to what ever the resolution of the PC. The problem that I am facing right now is that my form itself goes beyond the screen width.

Comment: It will do..I meant you have while designing forms you don't need to bother about the big resolution monitors. So keep design a form with small size and control width and height.With that you need to set the Anchor property of each control that will automatically stretch the controls and forms as per the size of resolutions. (Ex: try to minimize your visual studio and increasing its width and height by pulling its bolder edges. Then all controls in the window will be stretched as per the resolutions and towards size of the window. This is due to the Anchor properties)

Answer (score 0):

In the proccess of setting form dimensions, the form size is restricted by **Screen.GetWorkingArea** without taking into account **AutoScale**.

I resolved this issue storing the original **ClientSize** setted in **InitializeComponent()** and reset it autoscaled on **HandleCreated** event.

```
    private SizeF _autoScaleFactor;
    private Size _originalClientSize;

    protected override void SetClientSizeCore(int x, int y)
    {
        base.SetClientSizeCore(x, y);

        _autoScaleFactor = AutoScaleFactor;
        _originalClientSize = new Size(x, y);
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoScaleClientSize();

        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }

    private void AutoScaleClientSize()
    {
        var dx = _autoScaleFactor.Width;
        if (!dx.Equals(1.0F))
        {
            _originalClientSize.Width = (int)Math.Round(_originalClientSize.Width * dx);
        }

        var dy = _autoScaleFactor.Height;
        if (!dy.Equals(1.0F))
        {
            _originalClientSize.Height = (int)Math.Round(_originalClientSize.Height * dy);
        }

        ClientSize = _originalClientSize;
    }
```